# How to remove lines dynamically from text file?

Tags: java, io

I am making app that reduces txt file for my own customs. I found problem that I can't solve. 
I have two arraylist with position of lines between i want to delete text. The problem is that the function count all desired lines and add it to arraylist. So if i delete line 52 the line 62 (next line) will be really line 61 and so on. How can I solve this?

Here is my function:

```
    public void countDesiredLines() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "D:\\Temp.txt"));

    int lines = 0;

    boolean has_it = false;
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines++;
        if (has_it == true) {
            has_it = false;
            if ("".equals(line)) {
                position.add(lines);

            }
        }
        if (line.startsWith("[Content]")) {
            has_it = true;

        }
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

I've changed it to this but the same error is ocurred.

Comment: Could you show an example file and explain exactly what do You want to do with it ?

Comment: Could you share the rest of the code (i.e. where the comparison takes place), and also, would it be possible to translate at least some of the variable names to English ?

Comment: @endriu_l take a look at this hint.

Comment: @eitanfar code was translated and completed.

Answer (score 0):

Start removing the blank lines from bottom to top.

or
if you start from top to bottom, you can follow this pseudocode:

```
1) counter=0
2) while a line is available for removal, delete (line_no - counter)th line
3) counter++;
4) goto 2.
```

Comment: This is a java question, the pseudo code is not very helpful, not to mention that it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Well, the question is about solving a problem that the user is facing, & my answer provides the solution. It doesnt provide the user a completely solved solution which he just needs to copy paste, however, nowhere it is written that the answer provided by me must imperatively consist of the fully-coded solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't see a reason to do this in two phases, how about a one phase solution.
This is a working a solution:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    private static final String lineSeparator = System.lineSeparator();

    public void removeBadLinesFromFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        boolean content = false;
        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (content) {
                content = false;

                if (line.isEmpty()) {
                    // skip this line, and the next three
                    br.readLine();
                    br.readLine();
                    br.readLine();

                    continue;
                }

            }

            if (line.startsWith("[Content]"))
                content = true;

            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(lineSeparator);
        }

        br.close();

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);
        fw.write(sb.toString());
        fw.close();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.removeBadLinesFromFile("Test.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: More less i get it, the number of removed lines is always the same, it is 4 lines what should i do with it?

Comment: And were going in good direction becouse i get message like "End of file reached." ;)

Comment: so linesToDeleteOffset[] will be my position.get(0) and linesToDeleteLength[] will be new_position.get(0) ? app always remove 4 lines so it could be constant value. Did I get it ?

Comment: I check it and i will post what has happend. Wish me luck ;)

Comment: I added a simpler solution, take a look.

Comment: To your previous solution: I read out all pairs that where removed from file and it was wrong. Many of them was more than once used which is impossible. Take a look at this:
    Para: 9 5
    Para: 9 5
    Para: 604 600   
    Para: 9 5
    Para: 327 323
    Para: 147 143
    Para: 54 50
    Para: 263 259
    Para: 322 318
    Para: 9 5
    Para: 61 57
    Para: 300 296
    Para: 9 5
    Para: 384 380
    Para: 117 113

Comment: Is doing it in two phases a requirement ? Why complicate things ?

Comment: Your previous solution was quite well but something mess up, becouse as you can see it is impossible to Have 3 the same pair in four statements.  Pair: 9 5 Pair: 9 5 Pair: 604 600 Pair: 9 5. The position of deleted lines didn't changed.

Comment: Well, I'll leave some of the debugging to you. I think that both ideas could work for you with some tweaking. Good luck !